# Importing an old project in updated Android version

Tags: android, maven

While Running or importing a project in newer version of Android Studio got the following error even after successfully built
 - Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.0-5013011.

```
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/dimi1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.0-5013011/aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

This is the error message I receive. I downloaded an older project and found solutions to the other error messages. Yet, how can I fix this problem/error message?

Answer (score 1):

According to the directories, I believe it is a problem with the Android SDK. Try reinstalling Android Studio (but keep the project files), which will also reinstall the Android SDK with it. If that doesn't work, go to https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads, scroll down to command-line tools only, and download the right version of the Android SDK based on your OS. Go through the install process and hopefully that should fix your issue.

Comment: I downloaded android studio today, I want to find a solution to this specific problem and not solely, reinstall it. Other projects work, what I did was update each version and fix the error messages, for instance using implements instead of compile. But, this problem now occurred. Can this occur solely because of the written code?

Comment: Did this problem only occur after you fixed the error messages (implements vs. compile)? If so, make sure you are running the latest versions of Gradle, Android Studio, and the Android SDK. Also make sure that your build.gradle file (app level) has the correct versions listed. For instance, try setting the compilSdkVersion in android {} to 28.

Comment: Other than reinstalling or updating, I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: That did not work, I will retype the code then. Everything else works, I have problems running old projects. I am not that familiar yet.

Comment: Just add following code in project gradle..
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: @kamleshwerpurohit This worked for me. You should add this as answer